# How to distinguish 4"-5" phone from smaller phone

Tags: android-layout, android-screen

I am developing app which should run on phone and tablets.

there are following layout -

```
layout\
layout_land\
layout_large_land\
Layout_large_port
layout_xlarge_land\
layout_xlarge_port\
```

Requirement is to define different layout for 4.8",5" phones from say 3.8" phone.

but 5" phones are not recognized as large, they are treated and normal. What can be done ?

Comment: physical size has nothing to do with the layout size. it's the screen resolution that determines the size. e.g. a 5" screen that has a (stupidly small) 10x10 pixel size is not going to be a "large" screen.

Comment: Samsung Note  800x1280 pixel (5.3"), is being taken as normal and also ACE 480x800 (3.8") is taken as normal. But Samsung Note needs a different layout. The problem is how to provide different layout for these two.